# Spring/Hibernate: Keep session open for thread, or open a new one?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I am using Spring 3 together with Hibernate. I have a user request that starts a java thread in the spring controller and then a response is sent, so the thread might continue to work while the user http response has already been sent.

If I am working with lazy collections in my thread I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: my.model.MyClass.lazyCollection, no session or session was closed
```

I read I could use Hibernate.initialize(entity) to fully fetch the lazy collections but I cannot use this as I am filling the collection just in the thread. Furthermore I tried to use merge() but that still does not solve the problem.

Is there a way to manually keep the session open or to open a new one for the thread?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you in an web application, so that a http request is a thred, or do you something else?

Comment: Yes I am in a web application with spring mvc. However, additionally to the request thread I am creating one on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring to inject the `SessionFactory` into your `Runnable`, open a `Session` from it, and manage the lifetime of the `Session` and `Transaction` using vanilla Hibernate APIs without relying on the session management magic of Spring.

Comment: Thanks! Can I still somehow my DAO's the, that I've created by extending HibernateDaoSupport?

Comment: What features of HibernateDaoSupport would you be using in this case? From your description, you want to side-step the session and transaction management features. The only other feature yiumight want to use, as far as I can imagine, is the exception translation. That can be achieved using http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/SessionFactoryUtils.html#newJdbcExceptionTranslator(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)

Comment: @Erik Sorry, the earlier link is incorrect. Please see  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/SessionFactoryUtils.html#convertHibernateAccessException(org.hibernate.HibernateException) instead.

Comment: I now do it as you proposed and in fact its not THAT complicated. Just take care that you don't get messed up with multiple sessions et voilá. Thanks for you help!